# Switch window size in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

So me and a friend have made a tool using flex which we have released, we made the window 680x480 and people are saying its too small for them.

So what i want to do is include possibly a switch or something that switches the size from 640x480 to 800x600, so you have both options available to use.

I just wondered if this was possible? I have searched google all morning and cant find exactly what i need.

I am also pretty novice at this... my friend is the coder but he has no idea and no time to sort this out, so would be a great help if i could get some insight here please.

I failed to mention, it's not a scale, i have all the assets in the package for 800x600 aswell as the standard files so, i guess would be a state change, but i'm not sure if its possible to change state to a larger page.

Thanks.

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  When you say you made a Window 680x480 what are you talking about?  The size of your SWF inside an HTML page?  A web browser window?  An AIR window?  Or something else?  Based on that, what size do you want to change?  Do you just want to scale up your app, or do you want to re structure the UI based on the available space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically, you can occupy 100% width and 100% height by your SWF within the containing HTML page.

Then if you need a fixed size, you can organize your application within a Group container and size it accordingly.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" width="{resolutionDropDownList.selectedItem.w}" height="{resolutionDropDownList.selectedItem.h}">
        <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#FF0000"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
    <s:HGroup top="10" horizontalCenter="0" gap="5" verticalAlign="baseline">
        <s:Label text="Size:"/>
        <s:DropDownList id="resolutionDropDownList" labelField="label" selectedIndex="0">
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <fx:Object w="640" h="480" label="640x480"/>
                    <fx:Object w="800" h="600" label="800x600"/>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veeeeeery rough convertion from `640x480` to `800x600` resolution:

```
stage.scaleX = 800 / 640;
stage.scaleY = 600 / 480;
```